# Remove the resizing of images that are bigger then the max resolution. (reject instead)

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I'm using a very specific theme on the site where an image need to be exactly 1110x540.
I've set up the min and max resolutions and everything works perfectly, except when I upload an image that's bigger then 540px. Then the image rescales.

Is there a setting that rejects these images instead of resizing them ?
I'm using Drupal 7 btw.

Comment: Do you not just need to set maximum resolution in the field settings? Then the upload will fail altogether

Comment: Well no. This is the explanation of the filter: The maximum allowed image size expressed as WIDTHxHEIGHT (e.g. 640x480). Leave blank for no restriction. If a larger image is uploaded, it will be resized to reflect the given width and height. Resizing images on upload will cause the loss of EXIF data in the image.

Comment: Image styles don't 'accept' or 'reject' images, they just create an image from the options given to them. Form validation (i.e. based on your field instance settings) is used for validation; they're 2 separate parts of the system that don't talk to one another by default. Sounds like you'll need to write your own image style handler which does exactly what the standard scale/crop formatters do already, but while preserving the EXIF data.

Answer (score 1):

Set min/max on the FIELD ITSELF, under content types. Not on the image style.

Comment: I might have explained myself badly. I'm not talking about image styles, I'm actually talking about the field settings. If you set a max size, and upload an image bigger then the max size, it will resize to fit. I'm looking for a solution that just plainly rejects it.

Comment: No, you explained fine, I simply had never noticed those fields aren't actually limits but rather they are guides, having always used image styles to handle resizing and cropping. You'll need to implement one of the file upload hooks like hook_file_presave to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late... you asked this 2 years ago hahaha

The scale filter is in includes/file.inc line 1809, specifically it tries to resize the image when is bigger than your setting... if it can't do it then returns the error "The image is too large; the maximum dimension...". So you have to comment the condition... you just return the error.
I know editing that kind of files is not a good idea but at least for me it worked.
I'm not pretty sure but maybe you can use hook_field_validate to override that condition.